# Zend SOAP Server - Implementing a pre-existing WSDL to support a client

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, wsdl, zend-soap

QuickBooks Web Connector is a Windows client that can communicate with a SOAP server to synchronize QuickBooks data.  They supply a [QuickBooks Web Connector WSDL file](http://developer.intuit.com/uploadedFiles/Support/QBWebConnectorSvc.wsdl) which defines the functions supported by QuickBooks Web Connector.  I am using the `Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover` class to generate the WSDL, but QuickBooks Web Connector does not understand the response.

How do I write a Zend SOAP Server class that will implement this pre-existing WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up NOT using `Zend_Soap` classes at all, and am using the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit Server](https://code.intuit.com/sf/projects/php_devkit).  I'd still like to know how to accomplish this with the `Zend_Soap` classes.

Answer (score 0):

`Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover` is used to generate a WSDL from an existing class. Usually this is used when setting up your own SOAP Server / Web Services.   It sounds like you are trying to go the other way and get / send data to Quickbooks. If so, look into [Zen_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html)

Comment: QuickBooks has a WSDL that represents the calls that their Web Connector client makes.  I am trying to write a SOAP server that will support their client.

Comment: Ahh, now i get it..  So you need to do the opposite of of Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover.  Generate your class files from a WSDL. I don't think Zend has anything that will do this. A quick google search and it appears that there may be some open source generators out there.  One example found is, http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2php-interpreter/

Comment: I don't necessarily need to autogenerate either, I just want the ins/outs to match the WSDL.  I can't figure out how to do it by hand even.